# node modules unwanted files

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

I installed gulp and normalize with NPM and added my package .json file and then inside my node modules i have a lot folders that i didn't download here is sample of it

```
ansi-gray
angsi-styles
ansi-wrap
arr-diff
atob
base
arr-union
```

and there is more folder like over 30 folders and when i deleted those folders my gulp got broken, so i wanna know why those files exist and how to get rid of them

i had to reinstall them in order for gulp to work, but there are really messing up my node modules folder

Comment: Alot of the time when you `npm install` a module, there are other modules which are needed by the one you just installed. Whats happening is that the gulp module *needs* those other modules in order to work properly. So by npm installing gulp, you are indirectly installing other modules. Hope that helps.

Comment: Well i am following a tutorial and he installed gulp and normalize and his node modules folder only has those 2 files why mine has those 40 + folders ?

Comment: Well how old is the tutorial?

Comment: You can go to the actual npm page for the module and look at the dependencies it installs to verify.

Comment: the course was made 2017, anyway it;s alright i guess i just have to ignore them, but i have a question what do i have to do now to start using normalize for example, do i have to copy normalize.css from node modules folder to my css folder or what do people usually do